# The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation

Tags: swift, nsblockoperation

```swift
import UIKit

var bOpertation = BlockOperation {
    print("this is a operation 1")
}

bOpertation.addExecutionBlock {
    print("this is a operation 2")
}

bOpertation.addExecutionBlock {
    print("this is a operation 3")
}

print(bOpertation.executionBlocks.count) // the count number is correct.


// Q: why I can't get this object what's wrong ?
bOpertation.executionBlocks[0]
```

**[enter "*Bug Error*" image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd4ix.jpg)**

- I tested this part of code above in playground.
- Did I do anything wrong?
- What's caused this problem?
- How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please add your code as code here not as screenshot so we can test it on our playgrounds.

Comment: Has something been printed in the console?

Comment: I've update the question!  please check it again thanks!